# Is there a way to test the model that is passed to a webflow's end-state?

Tags: java, testing, junit, spring-webflow

I have a spring webflow that I would like to test that certain values make it to the model that gets handed to the end-state. During the flow I would just check the flowscope variables, but after the flow is complete these are no longer available. Is there another way to test the data that is populated in the model after the flow has ended?

I was using [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/current/spring-webflow-reference/html/ch15.html) to create the test but it only covers testing during the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a complete answer for this, but here is what I have found.

As long as the webflow has one view state so you can get the flowScope then you can use that for testing.

```
assertFlowExecutionActive();
// Save the flowScope for testing later
MutableAttributeMap flowScope = getFlowScope();
// do other stuff to bring on the end-state
assertFlowExecutionEnded();
// then test the flowScope
assertThat(flowScope.getString("someVar"), equalTo("someOutcome"));
```

The model has at least the flowScope passed to it. I don't know what else is passed, but at least you can test some of the items.